# Webpack MacBook Pro Build Speed

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using webpack for compailing react application with ES6. I recently bought MacBook Pro and build time increased for over than 100s. Does anyone have clue for that, because I'm using same webpack.config.js?
Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
devtool: 'eval',
entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'app.js')],
output: {
    path: "../../../../public",
    filename: "app.js"
},
resolve: {
    root: [
        './node_modules/'
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: [/\.js$/],
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
},

plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    })
]
```

Node Version: v0.10.48
Npm  Version: 2.15.1
package.json:

```
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Dev-Team",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "~6.7.*",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.*",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.6.*",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.5.*",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~1.14.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "~6.7.*",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "history": "^4.3.0",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.0.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^6.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.5",
    "react-button": "^1.2.1",
    "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
    "react-dnd-touch-backend": "^0.3.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.7.0",
    "react-geosuggest": "^2.0.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "superagent": "^2.3.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^0.11.0"
  }
```

Comment: *"Does anyone have clue for that"* Your new computer is faster? (i.e. has a better processor, more RAM, SSD)

Comment: Yeah, like a lot.

Comment: So then why are you surprised that you can now build faster? That just seems to follow from having a better computer.

Comment: Did build *speed* increase, or build *time*?

Comment: I'm sorry, build time increased. (Edited)

Comment: You'll have to provide more information, e.g., Node version in particular.

Comment: v0.10 is super old. You should probably use v6 or v7.

Comment: @FelixKling Tnx, but speed remain the same :(

Comment: That version of Node is also npm2, Babel is extremely slow if not used with npm3. Once you bump your node version, make sure you delete `node_modules` and reinstall from scratch.